# How many options are there to award gold, silver, and bronze medals to a group of $10$ athletes?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many options are there to award gold, silver, and bronze medals to a group of $10$ athletes?

Is this permutation or combination, and is there repetition?
I thought this would be a combination without repetition, where I found the formula to be: $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!} = \frac{10!}{7!} = 720$ I'm doubting that this is correct though. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: This is a permutation, and your answer is right.  There are 10 choices for the gold, then 9 choices for the silver, and 8 possibilities for the bronze, giving $10\cdot9\cdot8=720$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine as long as you care which athlete gets which medal (and I am sure they do).

Comment: why isn't it 3 possibilities for athlete one , 3 for two , ext, giving 3^10? since wording doesn't clarify only one of each medal are given